# In iOS what is the standard way to keep unknown Apps off your server?

Tags: security, rsa, signing

The App could have a private key hard-coded into it and my server could have the public for it and the App could sign everything.  But then a hack could identify the private key in the object code and write a malicious App that signs everything with that same key.  Then that App could use my server.

The App could do a key exchange with my server but how does the server know the App is authentic when it does the key exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In essence you cannot know.**

Reason is simple: since anybody can get to the client and have *everything* the client is and knows by reverse engineering the client (to which they have all they need to perfrom that), there is nothing that can prevent them from answering any challenge you might set to what the real app would answer.

You can make it harder on fake apps though. But they could (if done right) give the answer anyway.

E.g. how to make it harder:
The server sends a challenge to the client app to calculate e.g. the CRC32 (or md5, sha-1, sha-256, ... doesn't matter as such) of the app itself from a given start to a given end. If you set those start and end points to be fully random for every challenge you send, you essentially force the fake app to have the real app's compiled code in full ... So you place the burden of having to have the real app (not forcing it to be actually running the (unmodified) code, just having the actual unmodified code).
Take care that you would need to support the server side with allowing for multiple versions of the client etc. or you can't upgrade the clients anymore.

Anybody distributing a fake app would hence be forced to violate your copyright on the real app (and your lawyers would have am easier case maybe).

**Alternatives**:

To pick an alternative, you need to figure out why it's (so) important to have your client ?

If the client contains secrets: remove them, make the client display only and have an 3 tier model where you only let the user run the display part and keep all secrets on your servers.

If you get your revenue from selling an app, give it away for free and sell accounts on your server. Use authentication to do that: you can authenticate users (login&password, real 2 factor authentication , ...) you can also disallow them to dramatically change their geo location in a short time, disallow simultaneous logins, ...
But the price is the hoops for the user to jump through. And they might use other clients nonetheless.

If you allow logic (like e.g. used in online games) to use the power of the user's CPU to do things, you can still keep oversight on a logic level on the server: e.g. if it takes 5 minutes at the very minimum to complete a task in the real client, and if the client reports back as "achieved" before those 5 minutes are done: you have a cheater ... Similarly, make sure all important assets are only given from the server, don't trust the clients ...

Comment: swa66 you seem to know your stuff.  My profile includes an e-mail address.  (It's my anonymous e-mail address, but I do check it from time to time.)  Your profile does not have an e-mail address.  Can we correspond briefly sometime?

Comment: Look at WhatsApp.  They charge $0.99 for the App then you set up an account for free.  Are you saying that someone could reverse engineer WhatsApp and write a competing product that just uses WhatsApp's server? If so they'd even be able to message with existing WhatsApp users.

Comment: Your email: not seeing it on your profile - I guess they keep that private... or I might need more 'rep' to get to those features.

Comment: For a popular app the problem of somebody reverse engineering it is short lived: they'll change something in their client to differentiate it from the fake one and kick out the fake one (along with the old one) on the server, and continue that till the bad guy gives up (as it's far more work to reverse engineer vs. to make the changes)
But if you are into it alone vs. somebody using a sweatshop to reverse it, and/or have a high value in the server itself: you'll lose the fight.

Comment: Are you familiar with the adage "obscurity is not security."  Strategies that relied on design secrets were never allowed at any big companies that had a 500 person security department.  The rule of thumb was if the hack read your architecture specification and / or saw the source code, would he be able to hack the product.  But you're saying that WhatsApp's strategy is exactly that.  The old hash the time of day strategy.  Anyway I'd like to continue this discussion.  Maybe I'm allowed to write my e-mail address in a comment.  macci68@yahoo.com